# MS SQL - group multiple occurences into unique time ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with data similar to this on MS SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
+-----------+------+---------------------+
| MachineID | Code | TransactionDateTime |
+-----------+------+---------------------+
| 1         | 0    | 11-06-2014 00:00:22 |
| 1         | 0    | 11-06-2014 00:01:22 |
| 1         | 0    | 11-06-2014 00:02:22 |
| 1         | 0    | 11-06-2014 00:03:22 |
| 1         | 99   | 11-06-2014 00:04:22 |
| 1         | 99   | 11-06-2014 00:05:22 |
| 1         | 99   | 11-06-2014 00:06:22 |
| …         | …    | …                   |
| 10        | 0    | 11-06-2014 00:00:22 |
| 10        | 0    | 11-06-2014 00:01:22 |
| 10        | 0    | 11-06-2014 00:02:22 |
| 10        | 0    | 11-06-2014 00:03:22 |
| 10        | 0    | 11-06-2014 00:04:22 |
| 10        | 0    | 11-06-2014 00:05:22 |
| 10        | 0    | 11-06-2014 00:06:22 |
+-----------+------+---------------------+
```

Data is inserted every minute from multiple machines.

My goal is to group the data by "MachineID" and "Code" with a Start and End Date for each occurrence of a "Code." There can be multiple occurrences for a "Code" within each time frame.

The desired result would look something like this:

```
+-----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| MachineID | Code |    BeginDateTime    |     EndDateTime     |
+-----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|         1 |    0 | 11-06-2014 00:00:22 | 11-06-2014 00:04:22 |
|         1 |   99 | 11-06-2014 00:04:22 | 11-06-2014 00:07:22 |
|         1 |    0 | 11-06-2014 00:07:22 | 11-06-2014 00:10:22 |
|         3 |    0 | 11-06-2014 00:00:22 | 11-06-2014 00:02:22 |
|         3 |   16 | 11-06-2014 00:02:22 | 11-06-2014 00:04:22 |
|         3 |    0 | 11-06-2014 00:04:22 | 11-06-2014 00:05:22 |
|         3 |   99 | 11-06-2014 00:05:22 | 11-06-2014 00:10:22 |
|        10 |    0 | 11-06-2014 00:00:22 | 11-06-2014 00:10:22 |
+-----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

With "EndDateTime" being the starting datetime of the next code, or being the final "TransactionDateTime" if there is only one code for the subset of data being analyzed.

Here is a table variable with some example data.

```
DECLARE @Example TABLE(MachineID INT, Code INT, TransactionDateTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Example 
SELECT 1, 0, '2014-11-06 00:00:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 0, '2014-11-06 00:01:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 0, '2014-11-06 00:02:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 0, '2014-11-06 00:03:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 99, '2014-11-06 00:04:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 99, '2014-11-06 00:05:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 99, '2014-11-06 00:06:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 0, '2014-11-06 00:07:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 0, '2014-11-06 00:08:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 0, '2014-11-06 00:09:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 0, '2014-11-06 00:10:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 0, '2014-11-06 00:00:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 0, '2014-11-06 00:01:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 16, '2014-11-06 00:02:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 16, '2014-11-06 00:03:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 0, '2014-11-06 00:04:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 99, '2014-11-06 00:05:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 99, '2014-11-06 00:06:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 99, '2014-11-06 00:07:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 99, '2014-11-06 00:08:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 99, '2014-11-06 00:09:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 99, '2014-11-06 00:10:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 0, '2014-11-06 00:00:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 0, '2014-11-06 00:01:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 0, '2014-11-06 00:02:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 0, '2014-11-06 00:03:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 0, '2014-11-06 00:04:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 0, '2014-11-06 00:05:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 0, '2014-11-06 00:06:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 0, '2014-11-06 00:07:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 0, '2014-11-06 00:08:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 0, '2014-11-06 00:09:22.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 0, '2014-11-06 00:10:22.000'
```

Comment: Its a bit easier to show examples in a fiddle.  [I've created one for you](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2399/1)

Comment: Thank you.  I was unsure of the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but I think this query should give you the result you want, at least it does with your sample data and result:

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    MachineID, Code, 
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MachineID, MIN(TransactionDateTime)),
    Start_date = MIN(TransactionDateTime),
    Stop_date  = MAX(TransactionDateTime)
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      MachineID, Code, TransactionDateTime,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MachineID,  TransactionDateTime) -
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MachineID, Code ORDER BY TransactionDateTime) grp
    FROM @Example
  ) A
  GROUP BY MachineID, Code, grp
)  

SELECT 
  c1.MachineID, 
  c1.Code, 
  c1.Start_Date,
  Stop_Date = CASE WHEN c2.Code <> c1.Code 
                    AND c2.MachineID = c1.MachineID
                   THEN c2.Start_Date
                   ELSE c1.Stop_date
              END     
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c1.RN = c2.RN-1
ORDER BY MachineID, Start_date
;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle for the 2008 version.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a151e/16)

**Just noticed the SQL Server 2008R2 tag... the answer below, which was the first I did, requires 2012+... I'll leave it here anyway.**

```
SELECT 
  MachineID, Code, 
  Start_date = MIN(TransactionDateTime),
  Stop_date  = 
    CASE 
      WHEN LEAD(Code) OVER (ORDER BY MachineID, MIN(TransactionDateTime)) <> Code 
       AND LEAD(MachineID) OVER (ORDER BY MachineID, MIN(TransactionDateTime)) = MachineID
      THEN LEAD(MIN(TransactionDateTime)) OVER (ORDER BY MachineID, MIN(TransactionDateTime)) 
      ELSE MAX(TransactionDateTime) 
    END     
FROM (
  SELECT 
    MachineID, Code, TransactionDateTime,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MachineID,  TransactionDateTime) -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MachineID, Code ORDER BY TransactionDateTime) grp
  FROM Example
) A
GROUP BY MachineID, Code, grp
ORDER BY MachineID, Start_date;
```

See this sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a151e/2) for a demo (requires 2012+)

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part here is to separate the records into group by code with respect to the time i.e. 0 is group 1, 99 is group 2 but following 0 is not group 1 again but rather a separate group 3. I did that using recursive CTE. In cte1 we create a sequence per machineid. This is used in cte2 in self join. If code changes between two sequence numbers group number is increased otherwise it stays the same. Then we can group by machineid and group and voila. I updated the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2399/25/0) from paqogomez, have a look.

```
with cte1 as
(
  select *, row_number() over(partition by MachineID order by TransactionDateTime) rn 
  from Example
)
, cte2 as
(
  select *, 1 as [group] from cte1 where rn = 1
  union all
  select cte1.*, 
    case when cte1.code = cte2.code then cte2.[group] else cte2.[group]+1 end as [group]
  from cte1 
    inner join cte2 on cte1.machineid = cte2.machineid and cte1.rn = cte2.rn + 1
)
select machineid, code, 
  min(transactiondatetime) as begindatetime, 
  max(transactiondatetime) as enddatetime
from cte2
group by machineid, [group], code
order by machineid, [group], code
```